# Change DNS server in ZyXEL modem

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dns

The model of my modem is: **ZyXEL P-2802HWL-I1**, I want to change my DNS to **8.8.8.8** but I have a big problem.

There are two section for changing my DNS server:

1. One Path: **"Network -> LAN -> DHCP Setup -> DNS server"**
2. The Other Path: **"Network -> WAN -> internet access
   setup -> DNS server"**

Of these two navigation paths in my model modem, which should I change my DNS server?

Answer (score 2):

**Potential Configuration Considerations**

1. Change the WAN DNS server to point to Google's `8.8.8.8` IP address
2. If you are using the ZyXEL as a DHCP server to assign IP addresses to clients,  point its DNS to internal DNS server(s) (if applicable) or else use Google's `8.8.8.8` there if needed too

   - Essentially, this gives DHCP IP address assigned client machines DNS server(s) to use for their TCP/IP properties

Comment: So I should change "Network -> WAN -> internet access setup -> DNS server", Is this true?

Comment: @Yas... Updated my answer if that helps but glad to further clarify if needed.

Comment: Then how do we test it? Should it work to just disable/re-enable wifi? Or somehow expire and drive a new dhcp lease??

Comment: That might do it or else from admin elevated command prompt once you have the ZyXEL configured accordingly and ensure the wifi access point or router is connected accordingly to the correct ZyXEL network or port run `ipconfig /release` and then `ipconfig /renew` assuming you are working with a Windows 10 client connected machine. Be sure you have the wifi interface configured to get DHCP IP from the ZyXEL router unless your ZyXEL router wifi access point interface if what you are configuring directory to use the Google DNS via its DHCP configuration.

Answer (score 0):

In some versions, you should go to

**Network Settings -> Broadband -> Edit the connection -> DNS Servers**

Comment: Your image shows the wrong IP addr, I guess for OpenDNS, not 8.8.8.8 (and 8.8.4.4 I guess) as requested.  https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using

Comment: what does it matter the IP? Can't you read the issue within the scope? *The question is how to change the DNS*?